# Split IEnumerable in three parts: "above", "item", "below" with efficiency

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new[] { 1, 2, 7, 3, 11, 5 };
int item = (from x in list where (x == list.Max()) select x).First();
IEnumerable<int> above = from x in list where list.ToList().IndexOf(item) > list.ToList().IndexOf(x) select x;
IEnumerable<int> below = from x in list where list.ToList().IndexOf(item) < list.ToList().IndexOf(x) select x;
```

I want to find an element in an `IEnumerable` and split the `IEnumerable` into `IEnumerable`s that no longer contains the element that i found. The code above illustrates the result that i want to achieve, however i had to convert the IEnumerable to a List.

I feel like there has to be a way to do that using LinQ and IEnumerable only.
How can this be done?

Comment: First of all you could simply use `int item = list.Max()`.

Comment: Secondly, it sounds like you want to use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Default i read up on Except - it seems like it removes an item from a list - i can not see how i would split the result in two IEnumerable at the splitpoint.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So we have several sub-problems here.  The first problem is returning the item in a collection with the highest value of *some projection of that item*.  `Max` only compares the item itself or, if given a projection, returns the result of that projection.

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source
    , Func<TSource, TKey> selector
    , IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
    }
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Source was empty");
        }

        TSource maxItem = iterator.Current;
        TKey maxValue = selector(maxItem);

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            TKey nextValue = selector(iterator.Current);
            if (comparer.Compare(nextValue, maxValue) > 0)
            {
                maxValue = nextValue;
                maxItem = iterator.Current;
            }
        }
        return maxItem;
    }
}
```

This allows us to much more efficiently get the index of the item with the largest value:

```
var splitPoint = list.Select((index, number) => new { index, number })
    .MaxBy(pair => pair.number)
    .index;
```

Next to split the collection you can simply use skip/take:

```
var firstHalf = list.Take(index);
var secondHalf = list.Skip(index + 1);
```

There are a number of different problems with the code that you have that are resolve here.

You compute the `Max` value *for every single item* in your query to get `item`, rather than computing it once and using that computed value.

You then go, for each item in the list, and copy all of the items to a new list, *twice*, search through that list to try to find the position of the max item, and then try to find the position of the current item.  You then do that whole thing *two times*.  That means that you copy the entire array into a list four times for each item, search for the position of the max item four times per item in the collection, and search through the list linearly to find the the index of the current item (something you could compute in approximately no time by just counting) twice for each item.  This will scale...poorly, as the number of items increases.

The code here finds the index of the max item in a single pass of the collection, and then creates sequences that represent each half that each have virtually no overhead at all beyond simply iterating through those items.

Comment: +1 for `Take()` and `Skip()`. Although creating an extension may seem overkill. I would instead use Filipe's answer and use `Take()` and `Skip()`.

Comment: @rcdmk This adds complexity in exchange for both a useful general purpose method with wide applications, and also removes the need to materialize the entire collection into a list and then iterate that list just to find the item that you had already found earlier, again.  If the collection happens to be small enough that that isn't a problem, then that's fine, but the whole point of this question is to optimize the query to avoid unnecessary operations such as that.

Comment: @Servy Good point. You've won it. Thinking on a large data set and optimized way.

Comment: I'm a bit dubious about `Skip()`.  In cases where the leading portion of the collection is small and the trailing portion is huge, using `Skip` might be better than enumerating everything to a list, but if the leading portion is huge, every attempt to enumerate the trailing portion will have to iterate through everything before it.  If the collection is known to implement `IList`, it might be good to replace `Skip` with a method that yields items from that list starting at the specified index.

Comment: @supercat `Skip` already has that optimization internally.  If the sequence pass happens to implement `IList` it uses the indexer to access the items, starting at that index, and going to the end.

Comment: @Servy: Does it?  I just wrote a simple test with a class that inherited from `List<int>` but overrode `IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()`.  Using `foreach` on the object returned by `l.Skip(3)` used the custom enumerator.  It's possible that `Skip` is testing for `List<T>` exactly, and won't even perform that optimization with subtypes, but if it's looking for `IList<int>` I think it should have used it.

Comment: @supercat Right, I always forget that it doesn't, even though it should.  Hopefully they'll add it in eventually.  In that case yes, it could be worth doing that optimization manually and using a `for` loop to iterate from the index in question to the end.

Comment: @Servy: I can understand why that optimization is only performed when the enumerator is a `List<T>.Enumerator`, since I don't think the `IList<T>` contract implies that it enumerates items with zero-based consecutive indices.  It's unfortunate, though, that (AFAIK) there is no way for a custom `IList<T>` implementation to indicate that such an optimization should be applied unless it uses a `List<T>` as its backing store.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the extension methods where you can use the index. Look the sample bellow with the comments.

```
// define the list
IEnumerable<int> list = new[] { 1, 2, 7, 3, 11, 5 };

// define some value (max in your sample)
int value = list.Max();

// get the index of the value you want
int indexValue = list.ToList().IndexOf(value);

// find collections
IEnumerable<int> above = list.Where((value, index) => index < indexValue);
IEnumerable<int> below = list.Where((value, index) => index > indexValue);
```

Comment: @Mrchief: No. The OP was looking up the index for *every single item*. This supplies the index as an argument and is more efficient.

Comment: That will get inlined anyway by the compiler so that you won't incur the look up cost every time.

Comment: @Mrchief No it won't.  It can't know that the collection hasn't changed.

Comment: @Servy: But it doesn't, at least in this context.

Comment: This may not work since my values are not unique, i think 'IEnumerable<int> list = new[] { 1, 2, 11, 3, 11, 5 };' would generate a wrong result and remove both 11s.

Comment: @Mrchief The compiler can't know that (or at least can't prove it), so it can't elade the operations.

Comment: @Johannes Nope.  This would split the collection on the first item of all of those with the max value, which is the same as your code.

Comment: @Mrchief Oh, and while we're at it, inlining doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.  Inlining simply means taking the body of a short method and using that code *in line* in place of a call to the method. This avoids the creating of a stack frame for very short and simple methods.  You seem to be using it to mean caching the result of a method and returning that cached result instead of re-computing it.  That would be memoization.  Inlining does tend to happen a lot (although this method is complex enough I doubt it'd happen here) but the compiler/runtime do almost no memoization.

Comment: @Servy: I'm aware of inlining vs. memoization and in this case, I misspoke. I got mixed up somehow...

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you need to find the (first) index of the maximum element.  As a variation on Servy's answer, this can be done using `Select` and `Aggregate`.  Then enumerate over the elements before and after that index:

```
        var indexOfMax = list
            .Select((value, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(index, value))
            .Aggregate(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(-1, -1), (min, cur) => 
                {
                    if (min.Key == -1 || cur.Value > min.Value)
                        return cur;
                    return min;
                }).Key;

        var beginning = list.Take(indexOfMax);
        var end = list.Skip(indexOfMax + 1);
```

Comment: Rather than using `int` and using `-1` as a pseudo-null value, you can just use `int?` and actually use `null` to represent not having a value for some integer.  `KeyValuePair` is also specifically for objects that represent a mapping from one value to another.  For a pair in general that doesn't have the key/value relationship you should generally use `Tuple` instead.

Comment: Also note that while this does use less code than creating a general purpose `MaxBy` method, as is done in my answer, I find that the method is useful enough and applications of it are common enough that it's worth refactoring that logic out into its own method, rather than repeating the implementation of the logic every time you have the problem.  Your solution makes for less code in one answer, but can easily result in more code, and less maintainable code, over the course of a larger code base.

Comment: @Servy - I used KeyValuePair for two reasons. Firstly, for extremely small Tuples I prefer using structs to classes for performance reasons.  Secondly, in this case KeyValuePair really does represent a mapping, since the Key is the list index.  -1 as a signifier for an invalid or uninitialized index is pretty conventional.  As for creating your own `MaxBy()` method, definitely do it if you're going to reuse the code; code reuse is always good.

Comment: @Servy - also, by returning -1 for an empty list, the `Take` and `Skip` expressions result in empty enumerables rather than exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to guarantee that your `IEnumerable<T>` object contains items in some specific order. This can be done by either going with `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` instead of plain unordered `IEnumerable<T>`, or going with `IList<T>` which can reference elements by index.

When you got that figured, splitting gets pretty trivial: iterate through the elements by index or by order and add them to `IList<T> above` until you find your element. Skip that element and then continue iterating through the elements while adding them to `IList<T> below`.